# How to reprocess failed events from Kinesis?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda producer which putRecords to a kinesis steam. Sometimes while writing to kinesis I get Internal service failure. What is the best way to handle such cases where lambda fails to write to kinesis ? I have a retry mechanism on my producer lambda but even after retry attempts it fails to write in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach could be to use the **DeadletterQueue** with Lambda functions. You can configure SNS/SQS to create a queue and write all the failed events there and retry to process.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/12/aws-lambda-supports-dead-letter-queues/